# How to count occurrences of object by property value, and store count with objects in new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, counting

I want to count how many times the same value has occurred inside an object, and create a new object with the quantity added.

I have tried using `filter`, `map` and `reduce` but it didn't work.

I have this data:

```
let arrayOfObjects = [
    {name: 'Disney', type: 'inteira'},
    {name: 'Bottieli', type: 'inteira'},
    {name: 'Monster Truck', type: 'inteira'},
    {name: 'Xuxa', type: 'desconto'},
    {name: 'Pokémon', type: 'zaffari'},
]
```

And I want something like this output (make a new object without the repeated items based on the 'type' key value and showing the quantity of each item):

```
newArrayOfObjects = [
    {name: 'Disney', type: 'inteira', quantity: 3},
    {name: 'Xuxa', type: 'desconto', quantity: 1},
    {name: 'Pokémon', type: 'zaffari', quantity: 1}
]
```

Comment: So basically you want to count how many times a certain `type` has occurred?

Comment: Also, how do you want it to give the name `Disney`? What's the criteria in this case?

Comment: Yea, I want to count how many times a certain type has occur. For example, how many type 'desconto' has that object.

Comment: I want that the original data to be the same and mixed with the new quantity data for the items that repeated

Comment: So the `name` should only be from the very first one found for each `type` and just discard the other names?

Comment: _"I have tried using filter, map and reduce but didn't worked"_  can you please show your attempts. It's usually better to help you with your own code

Comment: The appropriate duplicate would be [group and count objects of array and create new array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50913026/215552)

Comment: @phil I tried too use them, but I don't how, so the code was trash and I delete it

Comment: @thalesGog Feel like answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564076/how-to-count-the-number-of-object-property-value-occurrences-and-put-that-quanti#comment95927138_54564076)?

Comment: I just want to count the repeated items and keep the original data mixed with the quantity/repeated times for each item

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all. Are you happy to discard the _"Bottieli"_ and _"Monster Truck"_ names simply because _"Disney"_ comes first in the array for the _"inteira"_ type?

Comment: @Phil I don't want to discard them. You're right, how can it be?

Comment: @KenoClayton How can I achieve the same result of your answer with more than one mapping values?]

Comment: @KenoClayton For example: make the new object only if matching key value of name and type were equal?

Comment: @thalesGog how would you want them included in the output then? Your examples aren't sufficient; you'll need to edit your question. How about in an array, eg `{type: 'inteira', names: ['Disney', 'Bottieli', 'Monster Truck'], quantity: 3}` (though `quantity` is now redundant as you can just check the `names` length)

Comment: @Phil forget about It, with the dacre Denny answer I can work It out, thanks!

Comment: _"I can work It out"_  that's awesome 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways this can be achieved. One approach would be construct a mapping via the [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method, which maps each `type` to the corresponding `item` with `count` data included by the following (note that the use of a mapping like this is an optimisation):

- iterate your input array
- for each iteration, reduce the input to an mapping where the `key` of the map is the item `type`, and the `value` is the item (with count)
- if a value for `type` key is found in the mapping, increment the count of the matching item
- if a value for `type` key is not found in the mapping, insert a clone of the current item being iterated in `reduce()`, with an initial count of `1` included for that item
- Pass the mapping created by `reduce()` to `Object.values()` to extract a flat `Array` of the items with corresponding counts computed during the reduction

Here's a working snippet to show this in action:

```js
let arrayOfObjects = [
    {name: 'Disney', type: 'inteira'},
    {name: 'Bottieli', type: 'inteira'},
    {name: 'Monster Truck', type: 'inteira'},
    {name: 'Xuxa', type: 'desconto'},
    {name: 'Pokémon', type: 'zaffari'},
]

/* Iterate arrayOfObjects and reduce() this to a temporary mapping where item counts
are aggregated. Once that mapping is built, we'll extract values of the mapping to
get the desired array result (ie with items, and type counts) */
let newArrayOfObjects = Object.values(arrayOfObjects.reduce((mapping, item) => {
  
  /* Find exsiting item with matching item type in our mapping */
  const { [item.type]:matchingItem } = mapping;
  
  /* If matching item found, increment the count */
  if(matchingItem) {
    matchingItem.count ++;
  }
  /* Otherwise, insert item into mapping, and also include a starting count of one for it */
  else {
    mapping[ item.type ] = { ...item, count : 1 };
  }
  
  /* Return the updated mapping */
  return mapping;

},{}))

console.log(newArrayOfObjects);
```

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Surely this could be done more optimally than `O(n^2)`

Comment: @Phil OP didn't ask for the most efficient method, surely you could suggest another more optimal method

Comment: @KenoClayton I'm still waiting for OP to clarify the requirements. Best guess would be `O(2n)` and since when shouldn't we strive for optimal performance? I also feel this question already has an answer in another post

Comment: @Phil yeah fair enough - updated answer. How about that?

Comment: run code snippet is returning error for the result variable

Comment: That's pretty slick. Good combo of `Object.values` and destructuring.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, specially to @DacreDenny! Problem solved.

Comment: @Phil bummer - how was that your fault?

Comment: @Phil ah yep - just noticed your comments under the OP